# What is the easiest approach to exporting a Sharepoint list in xml format?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, list, moss, export

Pretty self explanatory. I just need to export lists easily to xml format. Are there any tools that accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the method I use:

http://servername/site/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=YOURUNIQUELISTID&XMLDATA=TRUE

Works like a charm.

Comment: In rejected edit, @reuben.ahmed suggests that one should, "replace the server name and the query string value with specific values."

Comment: Here's a link that works: http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.com/2009/04/silverlight-easiest-method-to-get.html

Comment: Also note that you can append a View querystring variable to filter the results and/or get values from more site columns in the output.  get the View ID from the address bar after clicking "Modify View" from the ribbon.

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me. I had to change Cmd=ExportList

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the Lists webservice. `http://server/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`

Answer (score 3):

You can write a c# application pretty easily to connect to the sp list and export it out yourself.

A quick search on codeplex search comes up with one such program already made for this purpose! Hope this can help you: 
http://www.codeplex.com/SPListReader
http://www.codeplex.com/SPListReader/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15420

Answer (score 3):

Any chance that the RSS feed is going to be XML enough for you?

Comment: Very interesting idea. I never thought of transforming the RSS feed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On the SharePoint list click Actions > Open With Access > Right click on the table and choose export to xml.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? I just tried this and I don't have an "Open with Access" action. I can export to an Excel workbook, but it links to the SP list and doesn't let you export it.

Comment: ad "What version of SharePoint?": Can you edit your original question to clarify what SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: Well, it's tagged MOSS. That can only mean SP 2007

Answer (score 0):

In the actions menu of the list, select export to spreadsheet. Then open the exported Excel Web Query file and from the File menu, select "Save as" and save it as XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 'Content Query Tool Part' to export a list of pages on your SharePoint environment to a generated XML list.  My favorite feature with this tool is that you can sort and filter the content you want generated on your XML file.  You can learn more about it [here through this tutorial by Waldek Mastykarz](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/creating-rss-feeds-sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part/)